# No puedo generar el APK de android

Tags: android, android-studio, webview-android

Cuando intento generar mi `apk` en **Android Studio**, me tira el siguiente error:

> Error:Error: Found byte-order-mark in the middle of a file [ByteOrderMark]

Mi *app* solamente tiene un `webview` con un `link` a una web.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        // Activamos Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        // Url que carga la app (webview)
        // mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        //mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://mypage.com/login.php");

    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapp.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#00f">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="495dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Coloca el código de tu activity y tu xml

Comment: Ya edite mi pregunta e incluí lo que solicitaste, gracias :)

Comment: Tienes un caracter unicode, agregue una respuesta pero como otra opción si es que estos archivos contienen el problema, copia el código desde la pregunta a tu proyecto y trata de ejecutar la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un character unicode [`\uFEFF`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm%5CuFeff) en algún archivo .xml incluso podría ser el `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Para resolver esto dentro de Android Studio ve a la opción para cambiar la codificación del archivo que contiene el problema, seleccionas utf-16 y seleccionas la opción "Convert":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente aplica el mismo procedimiento pero convirtiendo a UTF-8.

---

Como otra opción podrías copiar el contenido del archivo dentro de notepad y posteriormente pegarlo a Android Studio, salvando tu archivo.

Comment: Es muy raro, te cuento lo que hice. 1- Me hice un nuevo usuario en windows. 2- Instale Android Studio de cero. 3- Cree un nuevo proyecto. 4- Edite el Manifest asignandole permisos para INTERNET. 5- Puse un WebView en el XML. 6- Puse el codigo en el .java. Y me salio el mismo error. Por que pasa esto?

Comment: @Strelok estas usando windows? Como agregaste el WebView desde la misma IDE o copias los elementos desde una página web?

Comment: desde la IDE, y específicamente desde el editor gráfico.

Comment: Luego de casi una hora leyendo en foros, logre solucionarlo pero cuando me generaba el apk no me dejaba instalarlo, en fin, no me gusta Android Studio, al final la solución que me funciono, fue hacerlo en la pc de un amigo